# Cannot run Visual Studio code script via symlink

Tags: shell, unix, path, visual-studio-code, electron

So, I built Visual Studio Code from source and intend to keep using it like that. But now everytime I want to open it I have to run a script from its directory. I made a symlink to that script in my /usr/local/bin but unfortunately when I run it it says this:

```
device:scripts work$ sudo code
Password:
module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './product.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at [eval]:1:1
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:50:33)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at evalScript (bootstrap_node.js:479:27)
module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/usr/local/build/lib/electron.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
/usr/local/bin/code: line 29: ./node_modules/.bin/gulp: No such file or directory
module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/usr/local/build/lib/builtInExtensions.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
/usr/local/bin/code: line 41: ./node_modules/.bin/gulp: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/code: line 50: /usr/local/.build/electron/.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/code: line 50: exec: /usr/local/.build/electron/.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

I perfectly understand that it cannot access some files, but I don't understand why. Are there any nuances regarding running electron apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, guys. I think I solved this problem. When I ran code.sh via symlink it tried to find necessary files in the directories from my PATH variable. As I intended to run this script from anywhere but original folder they obviously wouldn't be found. So all I had to do was exporting original script directory to PATH. 
As I didn't want to bloat my PATH I wrote a little helper script and made a symlink to it from /usr/local/bin/
Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/sh
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/work/Stuff/vscode/
cd /Users/work/Stuff/vscode/
./scripts/code.sh
```